# REACT - toggle active button class on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I need 2 buttons, one for the "left" and one for the "right" side. I've made a separate component (subfolder) that i am calling in the main file. When the user clicks on certain button it has to become "active", getting the "square-round--active" class so it shows on the GUI. However currently i am having problem figuring out how to do that on 2 separate buttons, only one of them can be active at the time. In my current code the buttons just switch active from one another when any of them is clicked. How can i solve this ?

```
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

    const toggleClass = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
    };

     <ul class="buttons-in-line no-bullets flex-line">
       <li>
          <button type="button" className={isActive ? 'square-round square-round--active square-round--min-width' : 'square-round square-round--min-width'}
          onClick={toggleClass} >Left</button>
       </li>
       <li>
          <button type="button" className={!isActive ? 'square-round square-round--active square-round--min-width' : 'square-round square-round--min-width'}
          onClick={toggleClass} >Right</button>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

I am making this as a placeholder for now, but later on i have to adjust the code to work with the backend, sending the users pick (left or right) as boolean value. I am adding the backend code below, if anyone has any idea how to put everything together i would truly appreciate it.

```
const inoAPI = new konfiguratorreact.client.api.InoAPI();

Getters:
inoAPI.getSestav().isOdpiranjeLevo(); // boolean
inoAPI.getSestav().isOdpiranjeDesno(); // boolean

Setters:
inoAPI.getSestav().setOdpiranjeDesno(callback(success, error)))
inoAPI.getSestav().setOdpiranjeLevo(callback(success, error)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently don't have any way of keeping track of which button is clicked. Something like this should work.

```
const ToggleComponent = ({ onToggle }) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClass = (isLeft) => {
    onToggle(isLeft);

    if (isLeft)
      setActive(true);
    else
      setActive(false);
  };

 <ul class="buttons-in-line no-bullets flex-line">
   <li>
      <button type="button" className={isActive ? 'square-round square-round--active square-round--min-width' : 'square-round square-round--min-width'}
      onClick={() => toggleClass(true)} >Left</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <button type="button" className={!isActive ? 'square-round square-round--active square-round--min-width' : 'square-round square-round--min-width'}
      onClick={() => toggleClass(false)} >Right</button>
   </li>
 </ul>
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = (isActive) => {
    setActive(isActive);
  }

  return (
    <ToggleComponent onToggle={handleToggle} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does work. One more thing if i may, is there a way to send the picked value as boolean to the main file where i am referring to this component ? 
For example, if the user picks "Left" side i have to set "isOdpiranjeLevo()" to "true" and send this boolean value to the main component so i can later on connect that with the backend. 
Same goes for the "Right" side, setting "isOdpiranjeDesno()" to true if the user picks this side or false if he picked the left one.

Comment: @Elrab I fleshed out my answer a little more to include a parent component passing a function as a prop to the Toggle. Note: At this point I would remove the state from the child and also pass down isActive as a prop since the parent is keeping track anyway.

Comment: much appreciated, will be much easier figuring this one out now. Thank you for clearing it up for me.